# Make my player paddle into an image

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to turn my player paddle into an actual image. However, I'm not sure how to do this.  I'm currently performing the image assigning options in my PlayerPaddle Class's init

```
class Paddle(object):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color):

        self.screen_size = screen_size
        self.XCenter = XCenter
        self.YCenter = YCenter
        self.height = height
        self.width = width 
        self.color = color 


        #Create the paddle surface on the sides of the screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, self.YCenter - self.height//2, self.width, self.height)


    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, self.rect, 1)


class PlayerPaddle(Paddle):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color):

        super().__init__(screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color)

        self.speed = 5
        self.direction = 0
        self.score = 0

        self.image = pygame.image.load("naruto.png")
        self.imagerect = self.image.get_rect()


    def draw(self, screen):

        super().draw(screen)
        screen.blit(self.image, self.imagerect)
```

Right now, I"m just drawing the photo in the top right corner. How should I fix this?

Comment: you have to change `self.rect.y` and `self.imagerect.y` to move it

Comment: BTW: `Rect` has many useful fields - like `center`, `centerx`, centery` - so you can create `Rect` in place `(0, 0)` - `self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height` and use `self.rect.centery = self.YCenter`. BTW: Normally I wouldn't create `self.YCenter` , `self.YCenter` because I have it in self.rect.centery` and it correctly moves when I change `self.rect.y` or `self.rect.left`  or `self.rect.right` or others.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the `self.rect`  calculation as it is in the paddle class, and change this line:

```
screen.blit(self.image, self.imagerect)
```

to

```
screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

With the code as is, you are just telling pygame to draw the image at the position given by "iamgerect" - but your imagerect has just data for the image, not the image position on the screen. So, it is corner is always at (0,0), which is were you image is drawn.